# Drupal Input Filtering issue - no <ul>/<ol>/<li> tags (FCKEditor)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, fckeditor

So Im working on a website and got stuck on this problem, Drupal is omitting my  tags in the body of the page/node. Ive tried changing between the different Input Formats and altering their different Filter. Ive also tried to create a new Input Format to no success

The Filters installed in my drupal is "HTML corrector", "HTML filter", "Line break converter" and "URL filter".

Is there a way to just work around the filtering or turn it off?

Im Using Drupal 6.2 and FCKEditor for WYSIWYG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the 'Full HTML' input filter, is it possible your user account doesn't have the correct permissions to use it? It's installed by default with Drupal so should definitely exist!

Comment: Yes, I have tried the installed Full HTML input format to no success. I also changed the filters it used and made a new Input Format that did not use any filters at all.

Comment: Check the FCKEditor admin settings, make sure the editor has been set up to use the 'Full HTML' input format, not 'Filtered HTML' or similar

Comment: The Input Format is chosen when I publish the node. No such setting for the FCKEditor.

Comment: Something is filtering the <ul> and <ol> (as well as <li>) tags. Both in Filtered HTML and Full HTML formats. I have tried to enable for example <h5> tags in the filtered html filter and the tags renders as intended.

Comment: Ok, my problem was regarding to the theme I was using that was overriding all html tags except <p><a><h5><br><strong><img><em> in $content. Top tip to others, check if your problem persists in one of the "default" themes.